# Shared element does not return to RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I have a fragment called `MainFragment` that contains a ViewPager that contains another fragment called `LibraryFragment`.

`LibraryFragment` contains a RecyclerView with a list of items that contain an ImageView. The ImageView's contents are loaded with Coil.

When an item is clicked, `LibraryFragment` navigates to another fragment called `ArtistDetailFragment` and uses the ImageView from the item.

The problem is that while the enter transition works fine, the `ImageView` does not return to the list item when navigating back and only fades away. Ive attached an example below:

[image]

Ive tried using `postponeEnterTransition()` and `startPostponedEnterTransition()` along with adding a `SharedElementCallback` but neither have worked that well. I've also ruled out Coil being the issue.

Heres `LibraryFragment`:

```
class LibraryFragment : Fragment() {

    private val musicModel: MusicViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val libraryModel: LibraryViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLibraryBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentLibraryBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.libraryRecycler.adapter = ArtistAdapter(
            musicModel.artists.value!!,
            BindingClickListener { artist, itemBinding ->
                navToArtist(artist, itemBinding)
            }
        )

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun navToArtist(artist: Artist, itemBinding: ItemArtistBinding) {
        // When navigation, pass the artistImage of the item as a shared element to create
        // the image popup.
        findNavController().navigate(
            MainFragmentDirections.actionShowArtist(artist.id),
            FragmentNavigatorExtras(
                itemBinding.artistImage to itemBinding.artistImage.transitionName
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Heres `ArtistDetailFragment`:

```
class ArtistDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentArtistDetailBinding.inflate(inflater)
    
        sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext())
            .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
    
        val musicModel: MusicViewModel by activityViewModels()
        val artistId = ArtistDetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).artistId
    
        // Get the transition name used by the recyclerview ite
        binding.artistImage.transitionName = artistId.toString()
    
        binding.artist = musicModel.artists.value?.find { it.id == artistId }
    
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

And heres the `RecyclerView` Adapter/ViewHolder:

```
class ArtistAdapter(
    private val data: List<Artist>,
    private val listener: BindingClickListener<Artist, ItemArtistBinding>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            ItemArtistBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(data[position])
    }

    // Generic ViewHolder for an artist
    inner class ViewHolder(
        private val binding: ItemArtistBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        // Bind the view w/new data
        fun bind(artist: Artist) {
            binding.artist = artist

            binding.root.setOnClickListener { listener.onClick(artist, binding) }

            // Update the transition name with the new artist's ID.
            binding.artistImage.transitionName = artist.id.toString()

            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I used `postponeEnterTransition` and `startPostponedEnterTransition` like this:

```
// LibraryFragment
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    postponeEnterTransition()

    // Refresh the parent adapter to make the image reappear
    binding.libraryRecycler.adapter = artistAdapter

    // Do the Pre-Draw listener
    binding.libraryRecycler.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener {
        startPostponedEnterTransition()
        true
    }
}
```

This only makes the RecyclerView itself refresh however, the shared element still fades away instead of returning to the RecyclerView item.

[image: Problem Again]

Comment: The [shared element transitions with `RecyclerView` guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/animate#recyclerview) does **specifically** say that you need to use `postponeEnterTransition()` + `startPostponedEnterTransition()`. Can you include your code on where you used those?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ive added my code for that. The problem with the code I used is that the shared element did not return to the RecyclerView item, it still just fades away.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem. Did anyone found the solution? If yes, please update

Answer (score 2):

Chris Banes says;

You may wonder why we set the OnPreDrawListener on the parent rather than the view itself. Well that is because your view may not actually be drawn, therefore the listener would never fire and the transaction would sit there postponed forever. To work around that we set the listener on the parent instead, which will (probably) be drawn.

https://chris.banes.dev/fragmented-transitions/

try this;

change

```
// LibraryFragment
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    postponeEnterTransition()

    // Refresh the parent adapter to make the image reappear
    binding.libraryRecycler.adapter = artistAdapter

    // Do the Pre-Draw listener
    binding.libraryRecycler.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener {
        startPostponedEnterTransition()
        true
    }
}
enter code here
```

to

```
   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        postponeEnterTransition()
        binding = FragmentLibraryBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.libraryRecycler.adapter = ArtistAdapter(
            musicModel.artists.value!!,
            BindingClickListener { artist, itemBinding ->
                navToArtist(artist, itemBinding)
            }
        )

    (view?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.doOnPreDraw {
      // Parent has been drawn. Start transitioning!
      startPostponedEnterTransition()
    }

        return binding.root
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. While I moved on from the need to use shared elements, This still may be useful.